# Onchange not updating image source with value

Tags: jquery, onchange

I am trying to have the users avatar change based on what account they have selected from a dropdown box. I wrote some jQuery that I think should work as I am using it for a similar application to do the same thing ( with facebook urls not twitter )

http://jsfiddle.net/JPT3K/3/

```
<select id="twid-4646464" onChange="updateTwPic(4646464);">
  <option value="billpull-1">BillPull</option>
  <option value="billpull1-2">BillPull1</option>
</select>
```

```
 function updateTwPic(postid){
    var twhandle = $('#twid-'+postid).val().split('-');
    twhandle = twhandle[0];
    var picurl = "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/"+twhandle;
    $('#twpic-'+postid).attr('src',picurl);
 }​
```

Comment: twhandle[0] will give you billpull, or billpull1 respectively, is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Not related to your problem: If you assign the event handler with jQuery, you can get the value with `$(this).val()`. It's a tad easier.

Comment: yes the id is needed for sending the actually reply. http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/+twitter_handle should give you their profile image. Felix Kling if I dont split the .val() then it wont be the value I need.

Comment: I'm not saying you should not split it. The emphasis was on using `this` instead of `'#twid-'+postid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code works fine if set up correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/86nfP/**

Note that I changed `onDomReady` to `no wrap (head)`.

So what went wrong? `updateTwPic` was defined not in the *global scope* but in the `ready` event handler, so JavaScript could not find it.
If you have had a look at the console, you would have seen:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: updateTwPic is not defined

---

You could simply attach the event handler with jQuery to avoid such problems:

```
$(function() {
    // this code runs when the DOM is loaded, no matter where it is located
    $('#twid-4646464').change(function() {
        var postid = this.id.split('-')[1],
            picurl = "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/"+this.value.split('-')[1];
        $('#twpic-'+postid).attr('src',picurl);
    });
});
```

You could also make use of `data-*` attributes, which would be even cleaner:

```
<select id="twid-4646464" data-postid="4646464">
```

and in the event handler:

```
var postid = $.data(this, 'postid');
```

Comment: would the data attr be supported in IE 7

Comment: This is part of HTML5 and IE7 does not support HTML5. But that does not matter, it will be interpreted as a custom attribute of an element. It should work fine. You should nevertheless use the HTML5 doctype for your document then.